# MySQL - How many slaves can be handled by a master?

Tags: mysql

Can someone please put some highlights on this, How many slaves can be handled by Master.

I have 100+slaves for a single master, how this process will work?

Comment: Here I am talking about asynchronous replication mechanism.

Comment: Ignore the chosen solution, the other are good answers for async replication.